# Typescript - type definition for own classes without importing them

Tags: javascript, types, typescript

I'm using dependency injection with typescript, means that I can create an object in a module without importing the class (I'm importing an Injector instead which gives me the object instance I need). If I now want to provide a type for the receiving variable, I get a `Unresolved type` error. Any good solution for that?

**Example**

An object of type 'MainHelper' is returned by `Injector.injectMainHelper();` but the type is unknown to the current module, because I haven't imported `MainHelper` (and I don't want to import it).

```
let mainHelper:MainHelper = Injector.injectMainHelper();
```

You can check the full code [here](https://github.com/mdix/diy-di-typescript).

Comment: Which IoC container are you using? Angular 2?

Comment: No, I just tried [DIY DI](http://blacksheep.parry.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/DIY-DI.pdf) for fun. So no container or framework.

Comment: I've been working on a container for some time now you can check it out at https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS also I recommend you to read http://blog.wolksoftware.com/the-current-state-of-dependency-inversion-in-javascript point two explains the problem that you are having here and why interfaces are needed.

Comment: @OweRReLoaDeD Thanks. I already tried inversify, in my opinion it's too much magic. Don't get me wrong, I don't want to say it's bad, it's just adding another layer of complexity. Thanks for pointing me to the blog, I'll check it out. I guess everything will boil down to use interfaces everywhere.

Comment: No problem! you are doing the right thing, is not good to "use magic" if you don't fully know what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about declaring interfaces?

#### interfaces.d.ts

```
interface IMainHelper {
    //... 
}
```

#### main_helper.ts

```
class MainHelper implements IMainHelper {
    //... 
}
```

## other_file.ts

```
/// <reference path="./interfaces.d.ts" />

import Injector from "./injector";

let mainHelper: IMainHelper = Injector.injectMainHelper();
```

Note: If you add the reference to your `tsconfig.json` you won't need to add it in the file.

## Update

I just tried and if you have two files:

#### test1.ts

```
class MainHelper {

}

var Injector = {
    injectMainHelper: function() {
        return new MainHelper();
    }
}

export default Injector;
```

#### test2.ts

```
import Injector from "./test1";

let mainHelper = Injector.injectMainHelper(); // mainHelper is MainHelper
```

TypeScript is able to infer the type of `mainHelper`. If you don't add the type the compiler will automatically detect its type.

If you have something more generic like:

```
var Injector = {
    injectSomething: function(somethingID) {
        // find something and dependencies
        return new Something(..dependencies);
    }
}
```

The solution would be to use generics:

```
let mainHelper = Injector.injectSomething<MainHelper>("mainHelperID");
```

But in that case you will need interfaces once more...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please add the definition file?

Comment: The definition file is `interfaces.d.ts`

Comment: Foo, I'm sorry.... worked 8 hours today, my brain is mud... :). Ok, this also would help with not depending upon concretes, but abstractions. I'll incorporate it into my project and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much.